# Exception has occurred: Object has no attribute 'ClientError'

Tags: python, api, error-handling, binance

Hi I'm trying to handle an exception thrown by Binance and output from the function the error so I can let the user know the API details didn't work

Source: https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python

I get this error already on the line for try:

```
'Spot' object has no attribute 'ClientError'
```

Unclear for me how to handle the ClientError thrown by Binance. I tried other combinations like adding binance.error.ClientError

Code below

```
import requests
import json
from binance.spot import Spot


def verify_api_key(api_key, api_secret):

   # api key/secret are required for user data endpoints
   client = Spot(key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

   # Get account and balance information

   try:
    return client.api_key_permissions()


   except client.ClientError as e:
    raise e



print(verify_api_key("test","test"))
```

How the Error thrown by Binance looks like

```
raise ClientError(status_code, err["code"], err["msg"], response.headers)
binance.error.ClientError: (400, -2008, 'Invalid Api-Key ID.', {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '42', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Wed, 16 Mar 2022 20:23:04 GMT', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'", 'X-Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'", 'X-WebKit-CSP': "default-src 'self'", 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '0', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 3ddbbcaacc1ba68ddfab04ef45c3ca98.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'MUC50-P1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'hBKLvd1lmcWNrI97jwGEnT2PH0jOXlvkMOkdfftTkAhqEkFEx8Xdaw=='})
```

Comment: binance.error.ClientError isnt going to work unless you import binance no? Maybe try importing the entire binance package to test it and see if that then works.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply unfortunately didn't make a difference

Comment: Just to clarify did you try it with having "import binance" and "except binance.error.ClientError"?

Comment: aha shit sorry it worked with except binance.error.ClientError with import binance. I thought I tried it before. Wanna make it into an answer and I'll tick it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the binance documentation it shows the proper way to reference the ClientError is `binance.error.ClientError`. You said in your question that you tried this, but in the provided code you only imported `binance.spot` - that isnt going to include importing ClientError.

Try importing the entire binance package with `import binance` and then try using `binance.error.ClientError` again. This should work for you.